# setting cookie in externalRedirect in Spring web flow

Tags: spring, redirect, cookies, spring-webflow

I am using spring web flow where I am redirecting to a external application.
The external application is within the same domain and uses a cookie to set some data. 
The problem is I am not sure I can set the cookie before sending the redirect so that the external application has the cookie already set to read the details.

```
    <webflow:view-state id="displayTerms" view="externalRedirect:#{flowScope.redirectURL}">
```

This the the view state which will redirect to the external application.

Answer (score 0):

Make it an `<action-state>` instead (or insert an `<action-state>` before the `<view-state>`), and have the `evaluate` set the cookie before transitioning to the redirect view. Part of the beauty of WebFlow is how easy it is to insert logic without making deep changes to existing code.